# Entropy applied to policy gradient prevent our agent from being stuck in the local minimum?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, python-3.x, policy-gradients

> In the information theory, the entropy is a measure of uncertainty in
>   some system. Being applied to agent policy, entropy shows how much the
>   agent is uncertain about which action to make. In math notation,
>   entropy of the policy is defined  as : $$H(\pi) = -\sum \pi(a|s) \log
>  \pi(a|s)$$ The value of entropy is always greater than zero and has a
>   single maximum when the policy is uniform. In other words, all actions
>   have the same probability. Entropy becomes minimal when our policy has
>   1 for some action and 0 for all others, which means that the agent is
>   absolutely sure what to do. To prevent our agent from being stuck in
>   the local minimum, we are subtracting the entropy from the loss
>   function, punishing the agent for being too certain about the action
>   to take.

The above excerpt is from Maxim Lapan in the book *Deep Reinforcement Learning Hands-on* page 254.

In code, it might look like :

```
 optimizer.zero_grad()
 logits= PG_network(batch_states_ts)
 log_prob = F.log_softmax(logits, dim=1)
 log_prob_actions = batch_scales_ts * log_prob[range(params["batch_size"]), batch_actions_ts]
 loss_policy = -log_prob_actions.mean()

 prob = F.softmax(logits, dim=1)
 entropy = -(prob * log_prob).sum(dim=1).mean()
 entropy_loss = params["entropy_beta"] * entropy
 loss = loss_policy - entropy_loss
```

I know that a disadvantage of using policy gradient is our agent can be stuck at a local minimum. Can you explain **mathematically** why subtracting the entropy from our policy will  *prevent our agent from being stuck in the local minimum* ?

Comment: what he calls loss function, you call `loss_policy`. could you edit your question with the formula for this loss function?